# postgres db imported from heroku to local not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I got the postgres dump by doing the following:

`heroku pg:backups:capture`
`heroku pg:backups:download`

Once the file **latest.dump** file is downloaded, I tried importing the dump to local db by doing:

`pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres latest.dump`

Db name and user is `postgres` I kept it default. Once I execute above command it creates something. But when I do `Model.first` on rails console  active record is still empty.

Comment: have your restart your dyno? probably it can help, and make sure the name of database (production part) is postgres since usually we using data_development, data_production etc.

Comment: @widjajayd dyno ? You mean rails server ?

Comment: yes rails server

Comment: Yeah. Actually rails server was not running at all when I ran the above commands

Answer (score 0):

After creating the **latest.dump** as a heroku backup. You need to run

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U username_postgtres -d db_name -v latest.dump
```

Then restart the rails server.

Answer (score 0):

You need also specify the number of dump in `pg_restore` command. For example `latest.dump.5`. To find out the latest dump number, search in directory, where you wrote command for downloading the dump: `heroku pg:backups:download -a your-app-name`. If this is your first dump, you don't need specify the number of dump